# SequelizeJS Error: TypeError: User.findAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) with expressjs app.

here is the code of my user model.

**user.js**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    bio: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    profile_picture: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'users'
  });
  return User;
};
```

Here is my user controller

**userComponent.js**

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const router  = express.Router()
const User    = require( '../../models/user' )

router.get( '/user', ( req, res, next ) => {
  User.findAll()
    .then( userResponse => {
      res.status( 200 ).json( userResponse )
    } )
    .catch( error => {
      res.status( 400 ).send( error )
    } )
} )

module.exports = router
```

But when i am trying to get the data it throws this errors:

> TypeError: User.findAll is not a function
>       at router.get (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\components\user\userComponent.js:6:8)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\StateBoard-Project\v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

[image]

Here is the model/index.js file which has been auto generated by Sequelize.

```
const fs        = require( 'fs' )
const path      = require( 'path' )
const Sequelize = require( 'sequelize' )
const basename  = path.basename( module.filename )
const env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config    = require( __dirname + '/..\database.json' )[env]
const db        = {}

let sequelize
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize( process.env[ config.use_env_variable ] )
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize( config.database, config.username, config.password, config )
}

fs
  .readdirSync( __dirname )
  .filter( function( file ) {
    return ( file.indexOf( '.' ) !== 0 ) && ( file !== basename ) && ( file.slice( -3 ) === '.js' )
  } )
  .forEach( function( file ) {
    var model = sequelize[ 'import' ]( path.join( __dirname, file ) )
    db[ model.name ] = model
  });

Object.keys( db ).forEach( function( modelName ) {
  if ( db[ modelName ].associate ) {
    db[ modelName ].associate( db )
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should require models/index.js where you're going to use models, not models/user.js.

```
const models = require( '../../models/index');

router.get( '/user', ( req, res, next ) => {
  models.User.findAll()
    .then( userResponse => {
      res.status( 200 ).json( userResponse )
    })
    .catch( error => {
      res.status( 400 ).send( error )
    })
} )
```

Comment: I don't have models/index.js file what should I do. In `module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {` I think `sequelize` is the object of library itself but what does the `DataTypes` object represents?

Comment: I don't have models/index.js file what should I do. In `module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {` I think `sequelize` is the object of library itself but what does the `DataTypes` object represents?

Answer (score 2):

Your *user.js* file is exporting a function but you never instantiated it.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) { // <-- function
```

When you require it

```
const User = require('../../models/user')
```

Now `User` is a reference to that function. Where does it get `sequelize` and `DataTypes` from?

Comment: Hi, Sequelize auto generated a index file in model, model/index.js, i have added the code above. I think this models are instantiated there.

Comment: Yes, but how does `sequelize` gets injected into your `User` model? More like `require('../../models/user')(sequelize, db)`. Then you'll need to import sequelize and db too before you can use it

Comment: anyhow, in your example, you are importing `User` from the 'user.js' file, which will give you the function I mentioned, not the instantiated model. I'll have in the docs

Comment: i think you have to instantiate the model using `sequelize = new Sequelize(...); sequelize.import('../../models/user.js');` which will pass in `sequelize` and `DataTypes`

Answer (score 0):

you should import your user model file.

```
eg. const user = require('../model/user');
```