# Sequelize build is not a function when model is created from migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my model which is create from sequelize cli: (it describes an user in User.js)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

When I try to create it in my script file, I get this following error:

```
User.build is not a function
```

Here's how I call the build method:

```
  const User = require('../models/User');


  User.build({
        username: message["name"],
    }).save();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it returns a function not constructor

> you have to pass `sequelize` and `DataTypes` while importing it

```
const User= require('../models/User')(sequelize, DataTypes);
```

Hope it'll work for you

Comment: Thank you, but it says ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined

Comment: You need to import it first using const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); But I am also in doubt about the DataTypes... From where we can import it ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar 
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require("sequelize");

Answer (score 0):

You need to require model from "model/index"

so change this

```
const User = require('../models/User');
```

to this

```
const {User} = require('../models/index');
```

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226104/9036923)